# Get child that last had focus

Tags: android, focus

I have found that when using a d-pad or trackball to navigate in my app if you move to the right and the list view looses focus, when the list view regains focus, a different child is given focus than last had focus.  I tried to use onFocusChange(...) to save which child had focus but it looks like this isn't called until after the focus is lost so I can never grab which child last had focus.  Is there a way to grab who had focus so I can then call requestFocus() on the child once the list view grabs focus again?

Unfortunately I cannot use a handler because this isn't a much used feature and I don't want to sacrifice the performance for a smaller feature.

Here is the code I had that didn't work (focusedView was always null no matter what):

```
mainListView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(focusedView == null ) { Log.i("focus", "focusedView == null"); }
            if(hasFocus && focusedView != null) {
                Log.i("focus", "Focus has been Recieved.............");
                focusedView.requestFocus();
            } else {
                // Focus has been lost so save the id of what the user had selected
                Log.i("focus", "Focus has been Lost.............");
                focusedView = mainListView.findFocus();
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are spot on with your own answer, bascially since the focus listener is called after its lost focus, no child will be in focus and therefore .findFocus() will return null.

I recon you best bet is to extend the ListView class, and override the onFocusChanged method. Basically do what you are doing, but do it inthere when gainFocus is true.

```
@Override
protected void onFocusChanged (boolean gainFocus, 
     int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
     if(gainFocus)
         focusedView = mainListView.findFocus();

}
```

[This one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#onFocusChanged%28boolean,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect%29)

Comment: That worked except for the findFocus() function is messing things up.  It looks like findFocus grabs the focus back to the listView and calls onFocusChanged(..) again causing me to never move focus.  Do you have any insight on what I could do about this problem?  Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: You say it grabs it back to the list view, so i'm guessing you are calling findFocus() in the case where gainFocus is false (the documentation says this will be true if the view has focus, false if not). I would try and approach it the other way around, basically, if the view already has focus gainFocus==true, then keep record of what the last one is. Then in your setOnFocusChangeListener listener, when focus is gained, set the focus to the last know child. I might be misunderstanding you, and you are already doing this, but the focus is being removed from child to the list. Is that the case?

Comment: @FuegoFingers can u post the solution , if you have  solved it ? i am facing same situtaion !! , i am trying to implement JustDanyul solution

Comment: Sorry this is so old and I've moved jobs since then that I don't have the code.  I really don't remember what I did to get it fixed.