# ListView Item Focus and Dpad Navigation

Tags: android, listview, navigation

I am developing app for Android OTT box, and i have to support Dpad navigation, now i have a listview on left side and a fragment on right size. 
when user moves to right , ListView loses focus and when it regains focus then different childview gains focus, my situation is similar to this question :-

[Get child that last had focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588807/get-child-that-last-had-focus)

as there is no satisfactory answer yet , i need some more suggestion on it .

Any leads would be appreciated !!